# "Access Denied" error when starting Windows Security Center service

Tags: windows-7, security-center

I am working on a laptop with Windows 7 Ultimate (32-bit) which had previous issues with Microsoft Security Essentials. I've removed the previous installation of Security Essentials and reinstalled it.

There's no problem with the said antivirus now, but after a couple of days it was brought back to me because of the error about Windows Security Center service not being started.

I've tried setting it to start Automatically instead of "Delayed Start", but I still keep getting "Error 5: Access is Denied." I've searched other possible solutions but it's mostly been either what I did already or "Don't worry about it." Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: I've scanned the system with both Malwarebytes AM and SUPERAntiSpyware and have found no traces of anything.

**EDIT2**: I have also tried running `sfc /scannow` to see if the files might be damaged. Got the message no integrity violations were found, however.

Comment: I am also having this problem - it's driving me nuts!!

Answer (score 0):

I found another forum post who said his computer was clean, but when he ran AVG anti virus he found an infected file of rundll.exe.

Maybe try installing and running AVG.